# Why do my FAILED transactions get charged the max gas price?

Tags: transactions, gas-limit, gas-price

I tried buying TEL on EtherDelta and had two failed transactions in a row, both charged at the max gas price, one after like 15 mins and the other instantly. How come I get charged for a failed transaction?

Comment: Hi there. To prevent people spamming or DDoSing the network. If this wasn't the case, anyone could flood the network with underpriced transaction without incurring a penalty.

Comment: (I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "max" gas price. You mean the value (i.e. your maximum) you set when sending the transaction?)

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter what was the result of your transaction, the computations were made and **you have to pay for them**.

This is how Ethereum blockchain works, if you send a transaction, some miner will receive it, make computations to execute your transaction. And in any scenario, `fail` or `success`, he made his work and he is getting the reward.

---

> I tried buying TEL on EtherDelta and had two failed transactions in a row

In your scenario you should definetelly contact customer support of Ether Delta.

---

> both charged at the max gas price

This part of your question was already answered [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/27966/9938).

> Failed transactions send all of the gas available for that transaction (the gas limit) to the miner. It’s kind of a penalty for failed transactions.